# Generating number sequence in SSAS 2016

Tags: ssas, dax

I'm trying to generate a sequence of numbers in a calculated table for a SSAS 2016 1200 Tabular model.

What i'm trying to achieve is is to generate number sequence like `1,2,3..100` in a single column. Just like the `GENERATESERIES()` DAX function does, but it is only available in SSAS 2017 and onward.

Is there a good a simple way to achieve the same thing in SSAS 2016?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in SSAS 2016 you can use CALENDAR and then cast the Date to an int, like for instance

```
EVALUATE
SELECTCOLUMNS ( CALENDAR ( 1, 100 ), "Value", INT ( [Date] ) )
```

here is the link to a working implementation on [dax.do](https://dax.do/eErz3qFalN7LEd/)

Comment: dax.do looks interesting, first time hearing about it

Comment: Yes, it's a new site https://www.sqlbi.com/blog/marco/2021/02/17/introducing-dax-do/